# How to complete the algorithm using algorithm2e

Tags: algorithms, algorithm2e, media9

I wanted to write this flowchart using

```
\usepackage[linesnumbered,ruled,vlined]{algorithm2e}
```

[image]

However, I couldn't get what I want, please refer to my code in below

```
\begin{algorithm}
\DontPrintSemicolon
\KwIn{Data 1,2 to n }
\KwOut{Optimal $\alpha$ and $\beta$}
\If{ Condtion 1} {pass $\alpha_{0},\beta_{0}$}
\ElseIf {Condtion 2}{pass $\alpha_{1},\beta_{1}$}
\ElseIf {Condtion 3}{pass $\alpha_{2},\beta_{2}$}
\ElseIf {Condtion 4}{pass $\alpha_{3},\beta_{3}$}
\Else
{pass $\alpha_{4},\beta_{4}$}
\caption{Algorithm to obtain optimal $\alpha$}
\label{algo1}
\end{algorithm}
```

[image]

So how I can edit this according to the picture I have attached?

Comment: Do you want to keep the formatting produced by `algorithm2e` or do you want to keep the formatting in the image? The `algorithm2e` formatting is very different from the one in the image.

Comment: @GonzaloMedina what ever, but I am familiar with algorithm2e

Comment: @GonzaloMedina Thanks for your answer, but it would be better if you could don't add a picture in the algorithm. Having said that my actual conditions are pretty big. So can't include the picture like that.

Comment: Then please add a realistic example of what you want to achieve. I guess I'll delete my answer.